# Using Parse.com How to retrieve an array of parse objects using iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, parse-platform

any help is greatly appreciated! I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, but nothing I found could help me exactly. I have a view controller with a table view in it and it works fine with static data. However I'd like this view table to display some user info from a custom parse class I have. So for each object, I'd like to retrieve a string which concatenates the objects first name with their score and their rank.
So my goal is to have a final product which is a string array, and to have each index of it being a different one of the objects in my parse class. I hope this makes sense!
Thank you for helping!

Comment: Have you achieved anything so far? Perhaps looked into `findObjects`?

Answer (score 1):

I can show you something similar that I have completed. I am thinking you would like to display a `UITableView` and populate it with objects from parse.

I use custom PFObjects but you should be fine. Also all calls I make are synchronous but you can adapt these to be async by using `findObjectsInBackground`.

I get my data from parse with the following:

```
- (NSSet *)clubs
{
    NSMutableSet *clubs = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    PFQuery *clubsQuery = [[[TSPlayer currentUser] teams] query];
    clubsQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
    [clubsQuery includeKey:@"club"];
    [[clubsQuery findObjects] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [clubs addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"club"]];
    }];

    return clubs;
}
```

I then assign the result to an array that I can populate the `datasource`

```
clubsCollectionViewDataSource = [[[TSPlayer currentUser] clubs] allObjects];
```

I make a helper function, you don't have to:

```
- (TSClub *)clubForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [clubsCollectionViewDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
}
```

Setup your datasource:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [clubsCollectionViewDataSource count];
}
```

Make your cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TeamCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    TSClub *club = [self clubForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = club.shortname;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = club.chairman;

    return cell;
}
```

I hope this will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example (in Swift) of fetching an array of custom objects from Parse:

```
func fetchPosts(user: PFUser, completionBlock: ObjectsCompletionBlock?) -> Void
{
    if user == nil
    {
        completionBlock?(objects: nil, error: NSError.parameterError())
        return
    }

    var query = PFQuery(className: PostClass)
    query.whereKey(UserKey, equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error
        {
            println("Error fetching user posts: \(error)")
            completionBlock?(objects: nil, error: error)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Success fetching user posts!")
            completionBlock?(objects: objects, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```